# How can I make overloaded function that accepts both matrix and individual parameters?

Tags: matlab, matrix, overloading

As a homework given by my Robotics subject, I'm supposed to make functions that convert between coordinate systems. Specifically we are supposed to do this:

> Function parameters are `Xo = mySYSTEM1toSYSTEM2(Xi)`, where:
>    `Xi` is matrix 3 * N.
>    Every column presents one point, elements of the column are then the coordinates of that point in *SYSTEM1*.

I know the equations for conversion but I need help with matlab syntax. I was imagining something like this:

```
%Takes matrix as arguments
% - loops through it and calls mySphericToCarthesian(alpha, beta, ro) for every column
function [Xo] mySphericToCarthesian[Xi]
%Converts one spheric point to another
function [x, y, z] mySphericToCarthesian[alpha, beta, ro]
```

Matlab doesn't seem to like this.

How can I establish these two function so that I can actually start with the homework itself?

Comment: MATLAB does not allow you to define multiple functions in a single file, unless the functions are nested. Perhaps that is your problem? You could try nesting them, or creating two separate m-files each containing a single function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, probably the simplest option would be to define two different functions. In Matlab, function overloading *shadows* all functions but one (*i.e.* only one function with a given name can be used at a time), which is not very interesting in practice.

However, if you absolutely want only one function with two different behaviors, then it can be achieved by using the `nargin` and `nargout` variables. Inside a function, they indicate the number of inputs and outputs specified by the calling script/function. You can also use `varargin`, which places all the inputs in a cell.

In practice, this gives:

```
function [x, y, z] = mySphericToCarthesian(varargin)
% Put your function description here.

switch nargin
    case 1

        Xi = varargin{1};

        % Do you computation with matrix Xi
        % Define only x, which will be used as the only output

    case 3

        alpha = varargin{1};
        beta = varargin{2};
        rho = varargin{3};

        % Do you computation with alpha, beta and rho
        % Define x, y and z for the outputs

 end
```